# apache 2.2 + php 5.5.2 + zend optimizer 3.3.3 in windows 2003 server

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, zend-optimizer

does anyone knows if it is possible to configure the following stack:

windows 2003 server with apache 2.2 + php 5.5.2  + zend optimizer 3.3.3,

it says in the zend website that optimizer will only run in prefork mpm apache distros, but I believe prefork.c cannot be included in the windows version of apache. I'm I right?

Is it my only choice to install optimizer over IIS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Zend Optimizer [system requirements](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/system-requirements) it supports PHP 5.0.x, 5.1.x, 5.2.x only... (and works with non-threaded PHP mode only and apache prefork-only mode), so...